# Adding xavier initiliazation in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

**I want to add Xavier initialization to the first layer of my Neural Network, but I am getting an error in this class:**

```
class DemoNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,2),
            torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform((nn.Linear(2,2)).weights),
            nn.Sigmoid(),

            nn.Linear(2,2),
            nn.Sigmoid(),

            nn.Linear(2,4),
            nn.Softmax()
            )
    
    def forward(self, X):
        self.net(X)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to try and initialize the second linear layer within the constructor of an nn.Sequential object.
What you need to do is to first construct `self.net` and only then initialize the second linear layer as you wish.
Here is how you should do it:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
class DemoNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(0)
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,2),
            nn.Linear(2,2),
            nn.Sigmoid(),

            nn.Linear(2,2),
            nn.Sigmoid(),

            nn.Linear(2,4),
            nn.Softmax()
        )
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.net[1].weight)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        self.net(X)
```

Comment: I am getting an error now : ``` RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #2 'mat1' in call to _th_addmm ```

Comment: Make sure the input to your network is a 1x2 tensor. For example a valid input would be: input = torch.ones(1,2) and then net = DemoNN() followed by net(input)

Comment: why only on the first layer and not on the entire network (I got the solution for that)

Comment: is the duplicate - nn.Linear(2,2) - at line 8 and 9 intended or just a typo?

Comment: @dpelisek the second nn.Linear(2,2) makes sense, as the output of the previous layer is 2 and the input of this layer is 2.